# Python threading or multiprocess questions with sqlite3 and matplotlib

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, sqlite, multiprocessing

I have a python script that I'd like to run using two processes or threads.  I am limited to two because I am connecting to an api/link which only has two license.  I grab the license by importing their module and instantiating their class.  Here are my issues:

1. I need to write to a sqlitedb3.  I tried to share a db connection, pass it to the "worker" and have it create its own cursor but I will get stuck with a "database locked" message and it seems no matter how long I keep retrying, the lock doesnt clear.  My program will spend about 5min loading data from a model, then about a minute processing data and inserting into the db.  Then at the end before I move to the next model, it does a commit().  I think I can live with just creating two separate databases though
2. After it writes to the database, I use matplotlib to create some plots and images then save them to a file with a unique name.  I kept getting "QApplication was not created in the main() thread" and "Xlib: unexpected async reply".  I figure that switching from threading to multiprocess may help this
3. I want to make sure only two threads or processes are running at once.  What is the best way to accomplish this.  With threading, I was doing the following:

   ```
   c1 = load_lib_get_license()  
   c2 = load_lib_get_license()

   prc_list = list of models to process

   while (len(prc_list) > 0):  
       if not t1.is_alive():  
           t1 = threading.Process(target=worker,args=(c1,db_connection,prc_list.pop(0))  
           t1.start()  
       if not t2.is_alive():  
           t2 = threading.Process(target=worker,args=(c2,db_connection,prc_list.pop(0))  
           t2.start()  
       while (t1.is_alive() and t2.is_alive():  
           sleep(1)
   ```

Comment: How do you load the client? Is it a python module that you import? And how do you reload it later?

Comment: after some investigation, it seems that my problem was different so I've edited the above

Answer (score 0):

Queue is probably what you're looking for, maybe the link in this previous answer might help you:
[Sharing data between threads in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044452/sharing-data-between-threads-in-python)